# How to run Junit.Jupiter code through command prompt in windows

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

For Junit4 compilation and execution, we need junit-4.12.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar can anyone tell me which all jars are needed to execute JUnit Jupiter through command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is via the `ConsoleLauncher`, specifically via the `junit-platform-console-standalone` JAR as documented in the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher).